# Azure Automation Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, azure-automation, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to submit a U-SQL job using Azure Automation on a schedule. However, when I use the `Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob` command, I get the following error:

`Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob : Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I can run the script using `PowerShell`, and it works intermittently, but occasionally gives the same error. Is there a method for fixing this error in Azure Automation?

**Edit:** The full statement is: `Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -Account "****" -Name "SecondJob" -Script $usqlScript` (I've starred out the account name for privacy). The $usqlScript variable holds a valid U-SQL script that runs to completion when submitted through the Azure portal.

Comment: Can you show us which parameters and arguments you are using with `Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob` when it fails?

Comment: @Pfav: This seems like an old post and you probably have already solved the issue. Can you please share how you did it. I also used to have these kind of errors, but it usually happens because of permissions settings.

Comment: Sorry never resolved, I moved on from this project without ever solving the issue. I was talking with Microsoft at the time to try and fix it, that may be your best bet.